# Add dropdown actions to Pyqt5 frame widget when right-click event is triggered

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, qt5

I have a Qframe widget and I already created an event triger like this

```
    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        if QMouseEvent.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            # do what you want here
            print("Right Button Clicked")
            #showMenuAtMouseLocation()  # to be implemented
```

I want a small menu list to be added at the mouse location (on the widget) which contains some actions as in the image

I tried adding Qmenu to the frame widget but it doesn't show

```
class TOCFrame(QFrame):
    def __int__(self):
        QFrame.__int__(self)
        self.menuBar = QMenuBar(self)
        exitMenu = self.menuBar.addMenu('remove')
        self.menuBar.show()

    def mousePressEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
        if QMouseEvent.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            # do what you want here
            print("Right Button Clicked")
            #showMenuAtMouseLocation()  # to be implemented
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `QContextMenuEvent`, and the `contextMenuEvent` listener.

You listen for the context menu event by overriding the event listener `contextMenuEvent`, then you can either create the menu or use a pre-made menu and use the event's `globalPos` attribute to display it at the point the mouse was clicked.

```
class TOCFrame(QFrame):
    def __int__(self):
        QFrame.__int__(self)
        self.menuBar = QMenuBar(self)
        exitMenu = self.menuBar.addMenu('remove')
        self.menuBar.show()

    def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
        menu = QMenu(self)
        menu.addAction("Option1")
        menu.addAction("Option2")
        menu.addAction("Option3")
        menu.exec(event.globalPos())
```

https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcontextmenuevent.html